# How to detect an error in a Tcl thread fileevent or after script

Tags: tcl

In my main thread I am trying to detect and respond to an error that occurs in a worker thread's fileevent script. I wrote a test script to try to detect thread errors in four cases:

1. Synchronous thread::send, immediate error in thread
2. Synchronous thread::send, error in thread after script
3. Asynchronous thread::send, immediate error in thread
4. Asynchronous thread::send, error in thread after script

I used an after command in my test thread to (hopefully) mimic a fileevent script. As expected, the case 1 thread error is caught via a catch of the thread::send command and the case 3 thread error is caught by the thread::errorproc procedure and by my custom bgerror procedure. The cases 2 and 4 thread errors are reflected in the main thread but I can't seem to catch them via my custom procedures.

Following is my test script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env tclsh


    package require Thread;


    # Custom error handling procedure for errors during asynchronous thread::send
    proc error_proc {id error} {
            puts "\n---------- error_proc: $id $error **********\n";
    }
    thread::errorproc error_proc;


    # Custom error and bgerror procedures to try to see the thread error
    rename error original_error;
    proc error {err} {
            puts "---------- error: $err\n";
    }
    proc bgerror {err} {
            puts "---------- bgerror: $err\n";
    }


    # Non-blocking wait procedure to keep the output in order
    proc waitms {ms} {
            set ::done 0;
            after $ms {set ::done 1};
            vwait ::done;
    }


    # Create the worker thread
    set tid [thread::create {

            proc test_error_immediately {s} {
                    error "test_error_immediately ($s)";
            }

            proc test_error_after {ms s} {
                    after $ms [list error "test_error_after ($s)"];
            }

            thread::wait;

            puts "---------- Exiting thread";
    }]


    # Test case 1 - synchronous thread::send, immediate error
    if {[catch {thread::send $tid [list test_error_immediately "Case 1"]} result]} {
            set state "ERROR";
    } else {
            set state "OK";
    }
    puts "---------- Synchronous test_error_immediately $state ($result)\n"


    # Test case 2 - synchronous thread::send, error in thread after script
    if {[catch {thread::send $tid [list test_error_after 1000 "Case 2"]} result]} {
            set state "ERROR";
    } else {
            set state "OK";
    }
    puts "---------- Synchronous test_error_after $state ($result)\n";


    # Wait so that the output is in order
    waitms 1500;


    # Test case 3 - asynchronous thread::send, immediate error
    if {[catch {thread::send -async $tid [list test_error_immediately "Case 3"] result} catch_result]} {
            set state "ERROR";
            set result $catch_result;
    } else {
            set state "OK";
            vwait result;
    }
    puts "---------- Asynchronous test_error_immediately $state ($result)\n";


    # Wait so that the output is in order
    waitms 100;


    # Test case 4 - asynchronous thread::send, error in thread after script
    if {[catch {thread::send -async $tid [list test_error_after 1000 "Case 4"] result} catch_result]} {
            set state "ERROR";
            set result $catch_result;
    } else {
            set state "OK";
            vwait result;
    }
    puts "---------- Asynchronous test_error_after $state ($result)\n";


    # Clean up
    if {[thread::exists $tid]} {

            after 2000 {
                    thread::release $::tid;
                    puts "\n---------- $::tid released\n";
            }
    }


    puts "---------- Waiting forever ...\n";


    vwait forever;
```

Following is the output on my computer:

```
    ---------- Synchronous test_error_immediately ERROR (test_error_immediately (Case 1))

    ---------- Synchronous test_error_after OK (after#0)

    test_error_after (Case 2)
        while executing
    "error {test_error_after (Case 2)}"
        ("after" script)

    ---------- error_proc: tid0x7f5673e9d700 test_error_immediately (Case 3)
        while executing
    "error "test_error_immediately ($s)""
        (procedure "test_error_immediately" line 2)
        invoked from within
    "test_error_immediately {Case 3}" **********

    ---------- Asynchronous test_error_immediately OK (test_error_immediately (Case 3))

    ---------- bgerror: test_error_immediately (Case 3)

    ---------- Asynchronous test_error_after OK (after#1)

    ---------- Waiting forever ...

    test_error_after (Case 4)
        while executing
    "error {test_error_after (Case 4)}"
        ("after" script)

    ---------- tid0x7f5673e9d700 released

    ---------- Exiting thread
```

I am using Tcl 8.5 and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Do you have any other suggestions on how to detect an error that occurs within a thread's fileevent or after script?

Regards,
smercer

Comment: tl;dr. Please see [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: Thank you @glennjackman for the pointers and I apologize for my long winded original (and first ever) post.